# iOS Files app won't open my app from another folder

Tags: ios, swift, file

I have an issue while implementing file-based features on my iOS app. I need to open some files inside my app, which I do with an UIDocumentPickerViewController. Everything works great.

Except… when I try to open Files from the iOS 11's Files app. It works as expected when the file is in the "MyAppName" On My iPhone Folder, but if the file is in a random folder on iCloud, nothing. The Files app only tries to display a preview.

Both **Application supports iTunes file sharing** and **Supports opening documents in place** are set to YES on my Info.plist. When opening from the Documents folder from Files, AppDelegate's application(_ open inputURL) is called as expected.

Someone has an idea? Thanks! 
I use iOS 11.4.1 on my device, and my code is all Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. For Files to open your app with your custom document type, you need to set **LSHandlerRank** to **Owner**. I hope it will help someone else :)